# EF Core Find method equivalent for multiple records?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

EF Core's `DbSet` has a method called [`Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1) that:

> Finds an entity with the given primary key values. If an entity with
>   the given primary key values is being tracked by the context, then it
>   is returned immediately without making a request to the database.
>   Otherwise, a query is made to the dataabse for an entity with the
>   given primary key values and this entity, if found, is attached to the
>   context and returned. If no entity is found, then null is returned.

I need to return multiple items based on the given array of primary key values, all in one request of course. Is there a method to do that in EF Core?

**Update**: I know I can use `Where` clause in normal scenarios. But I'm creating a helper utility that is generic, and in it I have no access to strongly-typed properties of my model. Thus I can't use `Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id))` clause.

**Update 2**: The desirable method can have a simple signature that gets a list of `long` values, and returns a list of `T`. `public static List<T> FindSet(List<long> ids)` that can be used like this:

```
var foundRecords = dbset.FindSet(new List<long> { 5, 17, 93, 178, 15400 });
```

Comment: Use a normal query with `Where`.

Comment: Please show a code simulates what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: *“I have no access to strongly-typed properties of my model”* – Then you will probably have to write some low-level helper for this. Using `Find` will only allow you to query one element at a time, which will be very inefficient if you have to load them all from the database.

Comment: Do you want this functionality also for compound keys or would it be enough if it worked for a single key per entity?

Comment: May I ask why you need this in a generic way?

Comment: And what will be the signature of the method in question? `Find` has `object[]` argument and returns `TEntity`. If we follow that, the method should have `object[][]` or `IEnumerable<object[]>` args and return `IEnumerable<TEntity>`? Please clarify the question by including the desired method signature and we will see how it could be implemented.

Comment: @poke, yep, I have an `Id` field in each table by convention, and I only need this method for a single key per entity. I need this in a generic way, because we're wrapping EF Core in a generic class that adds additional utilities to it. We need this because we can't copy those special additional methods in more than 100 projects.

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned in the comments, using `Find` in a naive way (e.g. looping through all your key values) will end up running a query for every single value, so that’s not what you would want to do. The proper solution is to use a `Where` query that fetches all the items at once. The problem here is just that you need to dynamically request this for the primary key.

Of course, the database context itself *does know* what the primary key for a given entity type is. The way `Find` internally works is that it uses that information to build a dynamic query where it checks for equality on the primary key. So in order to have some `FindAll`, we will have to do the same.

The following is a quick solution for this. This basically builds a `dbSet.Where(e => keyValues.Contains(e.<PrimaryKey>))` query for you.

Note that the way I build it, it only works for a single primary key per entity type. If you attempt to use it with compound keys, it will throw a `NotSupportedException`. You absolutely *can* expand this though to add support for compound keys; I just didn’t do that because it makes everything a lot more complex (especially since you cannot use `Contains` then).

```
public static class DbContextFindAllExtensions
{
    private static readonly MethodInfo ContainsMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods()
        .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "Contains" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2)
        .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(object));

    public static Task<T[]> FindAllAsync<T>(this DbContext dbContext, params object[] keyValues)
        where T : class
    {
        var entityType = dbContext.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T));
        var primaryKey = entityType.FindPrimaryKey();
        if (primaryKey.Properties.Count != 1)
            throw new NotSupportedException("Only a single primary key is supported");

        var pkProperty = primaryKey.Properties[0];
        var pkPropertyType = pkProperty.ClrType;

        // validate passed key values
        foreach (var keyValue in keyValues)
        {
            if (!pkPropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(keyValue.GetType()))
                throw new ArgumentException($"Key value '{keyValue}' is not of the right type");
        }

        // retrieve member info for primary key
        var pkMemberInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(pkProperty.Name);
        if (pkMemberInfo == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Type does not contain the primary key as an accessible property");

        // build lambda expression
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");
        var body = Expression.Call(null, ContainsMethod,
            Expression.Constant(keyValues),
            Expression.Convert(Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, pkMemberInfo), typeof(object)));
        var predicateExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);

        // run query
        return dbContext.Set<T>().Where(predicateExpression).ToArrayAsync();
    }
}
```

Usage is like this:

```
// pass in params
var result = await dbContext.FindAllAsync<MyEntity>(1, 2, 3, 4);

// or an object array
var result = await dbContext.FindAllAsync<MyEntity>(new object[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
```

I also added some basic validation, so things like `context.FindAllAsync<MyEntity>(1, 2, "foo")` will fail early.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that the number of database round trips could be one too many, if all the entities are already tracked by EF.

Comment: You can replace code `pkMemberInfo` to `pkProperty.PropertyInfo` now, if it isn't a shadow or mapped field. (but how ever who will make the primary key as a shadow property?)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make a generic lookup method that finds all rows matching a list of primary keys, you can achieve this by inheriting those entity types from a base class in which they share the same name for the Primary Key column.

Think about it this way: how would that method behave if your entity (database table) has a composite key? So if you can conform to this type of design, the following implementation shows a simple logic to achieve this with .NET Core. (Actually, you can achieve the same behavior with EF6 as well)

```
public class MyBaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class MyTable : MyBaseEntity
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public static class RepositoryExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> FindMatches<T>(this DbContext db, IEnumerable<int> keys)
        where T : MyBaseEntity
        => db.Set<T>().Where(x => keys.Contains(x.Id));

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Initialize your own DbContext.
        var db = new DbContext(null);
        // Usage:
        var lookupKeys = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        var results = db.FindMatches<MyTable>(lookupKeys).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear @Saeid, thanks for answering. But as I wrote in the update, I can't use `x.Id` here. And I don't intend to use a base entity simply because of an `Id` field. Again thank you for answering.

Comment: If you want to achieve something that dynamic, you have to look into the table metadata first before you generate the SQL statement to retrieve the values. First of all, what you're asking is a "Magic" function, which automatically finds the primary key of a table, and filters the rows base on the provided lookup values. Besides the fact that Magic code is a bad practice, it will be extremely inefficient as it has to make some round trips to the database to figure out the primary key first. Correct me if I didn't get your requirements right.

Comment: Another suggestion before you give up! Look into Dynamic Linq with EF Core. Maybe it helps you build something reletively close to what you're looking for. https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/

Comment: I actually did it using Dynamic Linq. But I'm still interested in seeing if it's possible to be done without that library or not. Thanks for guiding.

Answer (score 2):

I was recently looking for the same thing as you and ended up implementing it myself after doing a bit of research and some trial and error.

I know that the question is old but I though that other might look for a solution to this need (like I did).

Working in .Net Core 2 I ended up creating 2 extension methods to DBContext that looks like this:

```
    public static IQueryable Set(this DbContext context, Type T)
    {
        // Get the generic type definition
        MethodInfo method =
            typeof(DbContext).GetMethod(nameof(DbContext.Set), BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        // Build a method with the specific type argument you're interested in
        method = method.MakeGenericMethod(T);

        return method.Invoke(context, null) as IQueryable;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<object> FindAll(this DbContext context, Type T, IEnumerable<object> ids)
    {
        // Set the base entity (T) parameter for the lambda and property expressions
        var xParameter = Expression.Parameter(T, "a");

        // Retrieve the primary key name from the model and set the property expression
        var primaryKeyName = context.Model.FindEntityType(T).FindPrimaryKey().Properties.First().Name;
        var xId = Expression.Property(xParameter, primaryKeyName);

        var idType = xId.Type;

        // Set the constant expression with the list of id you want to search for
        var xIds = Expression.Constant(ids, typeof(IEnumerable<object>));

        // Create the Expression call for the CastEnumerable extension method below 
        var xCastEnumerable = Expression.Call(typeof(IEnumerableExtensions), "CastEnumerable",new[]{idType},xIds);

        // Create the expression call for the "Contains" method that will be called on the list
        // of id that was cast just above with the id property expression as the parameter
        var xContainsMethod = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Contains",new[]{idType},xCastEnumerable, xId);

        // Create a lambda expression with the "Contains" expression joined with the base entity (T) parameter
        var xWhereLambda = Expression.Lambda(xContainsMethod, xParameter);

        // Get the "Queryable.Where" method info
        var whereMethodInfo = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals("Where") && x.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType.GetGenericType().GenericTypeArguments.Length == 2).MakeGenericMethod(T);

        // Call the where method on the DbSet<T> with the lambda expression that compares the list of id with the entity's Id
        return whereMethodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] {context.Set(T),xWhereLambda}) as IEnumerable<object>;
    }
```

The second extension method depends on a IEnumerable extension method called CastToList that looks like this:

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> CastEnumerable<T>(this IEnumerable<object> sourceEnum)
    {
        if(sourceEnum == null)
            return new List<T>();

        try
        {
            // Covert the objects in the list to the target type (T) 
            // (this allows to receive other types and then convert in the desired type)
            var convertedEnum = sourceEnum.Select(x => Convert.ChangeType(x, typeof(T)));
            // Cast the IEnumerable<object> to IEnumerable<T>
            return convertedEnum.Cast<T>();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException($"There was a problem converting {sourceEnum.GetType()} to {typeof(IEnumerable<T>)}", e);
        }
    }
}
```

I've added comments in the code to help you better understand what I did.

You can call the "FindAll" like this:

```
yourDbContext.FindAll(entityType, ids)
```

Obviously, this might not fit the needs of everyone as is and might need some tweaking to achieve the desired result but it should provide a solid starting point.

In the code above, I assume that the primary key is only composed of a single property. It would be most definitely possible to modify the code to cover composite keys but it goes beyond what you were looking for.

I hope this will help others looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

### Composite keys supported solution

A solution inspired by @poke answer. It fulfills the following

- [x] Supports composite keys
- [x] Fetches all the items at once
- [x] Entity agnostic, no base entity needed, works with any keys and types
- [x] FAST, finds by primary keys which are indexed by default in most SQL engines
- [x] Easy SQL translation
- [x] Plain/simple short one method snippet (KISS)
- [x] Async
- [x] DbContext Extension

```cs
        // FIND ALL
        // ===============================================================
        /// <summary>
        /// Tries to get all entities by their primary keys. Return all/partial/empty array of database entities.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TEntity"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="dbContext"></param>
        /// <param name="args"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static async Task<TEntity[]> FindAllAsync<TEntity>(this DbContext dbContext, IEnumerable<TEntity> args) where TEntity : class
        {
            return await Task.Run(() => { 
                var dbParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), typeof(TEntity).Name);

                var properties = dbContext.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(TEntity)).FindPrimaryKey()?.Properties;

                if (properties == null)
                    throw new ArgumentException($"{typeof(TEntity).FullName} does not have a primary key specified.");

                if (args == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException($"Entities to find argument cannot be null");

                if (!args.Any())
                    return Enumerable.Empty<TEntity>().ToArray();

                var aggregatedExpression = args.Select(entity =>
                {
                    var entry = dbContext.Entry(entity);

                    return properties.Select(p =>
                    {
                        var dbProp = dbParameter.Type.GetProperty(p.Name); 
                        var left = Expression.Property(dbParameter, dbProp); 

                        var argValue = entry.Property(p.Name).CurrentValue;
                        var right = Expression.Constant(argValue);

                        return Expression.Equal(left, right);
                    })
                    .Aggregate((acc, next) => Expression.And(acc, next));
                })
                .Aggregate((acc, next) => Expression.OrElse(acc, next));

                var whereMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().First(m => m.Name == "Where" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2);
                MethodInfo genericWhereMethod = whereMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TEntity));

                var whereLambda = Expression.Lambda(aggregatedExpression, dbParameter);

                var set = dbContext.Set<TEntity>();
                var func = whereLambda.Compile();

                var result = genericWhereMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { set, func}) as IEnumerable<TEntity>;

                return result.ToArray();
            });
        }
```

Comment if use it (ﾉ◕ヮ◕)ﾉ*✲ﾟ*｡⋆

Comment: I've tried this myself, and, unfortunately, it is not fast. `Enumerable.Where()` pulls the entire table before applying the filters, making it extremely slow for large tables. Use `Queryable.Where()` instead, as seen in Nicolas's answer.

Comment: In overall, it looks good. There are some tricky bits to be able to use it. For example, the 'args' is passed 1-by-1 to dbContext.Entry(), so args MUST carry the entity objects already, not just PKs. Fortunatelly, they might be fake/dummy/empty detached entities that were a moment ago created on the fly, they exist only to provide a list of structured PKs (and they get attached so EF will fill them up, nice).

Comment: But the thing that MichaelBugglin wrote is also true. While And/OrElse is properly built as an expression, it is later passed to method obtained in `typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().First(m => m.Name == "Where"...` which clearly binds it to Enumerable.Where and executes whole filtering on entity objects in-memory instead of getting it translated to SQL/etc and be execd on-database. Since `whereLambda` is compiled and invoked on `DbSet<TE> set`, there's a high chance that simply changing `typeof(Enumerable)` to `typeof(Queryable)` and adjusting method lookup will do the trick. Not tried though!

Answer (score 0):

Alright. I tried **AliAlmutawakel** code snippet on a simple trivial 'People' table and it really executed as fetch-whole-table and filter-in-memory. The generated SQL query was basicaly

```
SELECT ...
FROM "People" AS p
```

So, despite how good the idea and the code looked at first sight, that's actually VERY BAD IDEA. No, not IDEA. Idea is fine. Implementation was not good. In several aspects. But nevermind.

I did some quick cleanups.

```
    // FIND ALL
    // ===============================================================
    /// <summary>
    /// Tries to get all entities by their primary keys. Return all/partial/empty array of database entities.
    /// </summary>
    public static IQueryable<TEntity> FindAllAsync<TEntity>(this DbContext dbContext, IEnumerable<TEntity> entitiesToFind, bool invert = false) where TEntity : class
        => dbContext.Set<TEntity>().FindAllAsync(entitiesToFind, invert);

    // FIND ALL
    // ===============================================================
    /// <summary>
    /// Tries to get all entities by their primary keys. Return all/partial/empty array of database entities.
    /// </summary>
    public static IQueryable<TEntity> FindAllAsync<TEntity>(this DbSet<TEntity> set, IEnumerable<TEntity> entitiesToFind, bool invert = false) where TEntity : class
    {
            var args = entitiesToFind;
            var dbParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), typeof(TEntity).Name);

            var properties = set.EntityType.FindPrimaryKey()?.Properties;

            if (properties == null)
                throw new ArgumentException($"{typeof(TEntity).FullName} is not an entity, or does not have a primary key specified.");

            if (args == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(args));

            if (!args.Any())
                return Enumerable.Empty<TEntity>().AsQueryable();

            Expression aggregatedExpression = args.Select(entity =>
            {
                var entry = set.Entry(entity);

                return properties.Select(p =>
                {
                    var dbProp = dbParameter.Type.GetProperty(p.Name); 
                    var left = Expression.Property(dbParameter, dbProp); 

                    var argValue = entry.Property(p.Name).CurrentValue;
                    var right = Expression.Constant(argValue);

                    return Expression.Equal(left, right);
                })
                .Aggregate((acc, next) => Expression.And(acc, next));
            })
            .Aggregate((acc, next) => Expression.OrElse(acc, next));

            if (invert) aggregatedExpression = Expression.Not(aggregatedExpression);

            return set.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(aggregatedExpression, dbParameter));
    }
```

*Tiny font footprint notes:*

This code was roughly tested, and successfully generates SQL query like below, but I might have overlooked some other glaring issues, so do not consider it production-ready. I encourage everyone using Ali's original code to take a look. I made as few changes as possible, so you can DIFF this code with Ali's code easily and see all the changes and verify they match your needs.

```
SELECT ...
FROM "People" AS p WHERE p."Id" IN ('test_id_001', 'test_id_002')
```

You might notice I added 'invert' parameter. If you ever had to run a 'find me everything except these IDs', the query code would look afwul, and that's just one line here, so why not?

This code returns a queryable, so the caller has to `.ToArray/List/Async`, but that's a feature - thanks to that the caller can also attach any number of additional LINQ processing and have them properly translated to SQL.

**Comment if use it (ﾉ◕ヮ◕)ﾉ✲ﾟ｡⋆**

- [?] Supports composite keys     (NOT TESTED)
- [v] Fetches all the items at once
- [v] Entity agnostic, no base entity needed
- [v] Finds by primary keys
- [v] Async-friendly
- [v] DbContext extension
- [v] DbSet extension